# Hide the long URL when opening or editing Xpages

Tags: xpages

Is it possible to hide the URL of the action of opening or editing a document in a XPage?

I am trying to avoid this:
http(example)://notesdev1.my_company.com/po/po.nsf/%24%24OpenDominoDocument.xsp?databaseName=CN=My_Company_NotesDev1/O=HCI!!PO%5CPO-data.nsf&documentId=E879C68A9A88F6DD87257BC6005A0748&action=editDocument"

I don't think you can use site documents for URL's that open specific documents.   I started out customizing the 'Default Action' and 'Document id' of the Document data source.  I then switched and tried rebuilding the URL in the beforePageLoad event, and using context.redirectToPage but it still shows the long URL.

I would like to know if I can have control over the entire URL, and still direct pages as I see fit.  I know that I can't stop a user from Bookmarking, but if I can control the URL, I can prevent the user from bookmarking intermediate steps in a wizard, and also avoid ugly URLs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a website document to mask those long urls. Your short url needs to have the DocId visible and then you can map it by a substitution rule.

The other option is to compute your data source. You set it to ignore request parameters and use your own:

```
http://yourserver/some.nsf/thexpage.xsp?doc=unid
```

Then use the context to retrieve the Unid and compute

Comment: Stephan,  If you are still online, do you know of any resources for the second option.  I think that would be my prefered.  My goal today is to get this to work, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Stephan, I have not been very successful.  Can you elaborate how you compute your data source?  Do you mean not binding the xpage to anything, and then binding elements into to the backing bean?  Do I try to bind to a Object, and use the object to launch the document?  I am not finding much out there in googleland.   THANKS!

Comment: Steve, you compute the documentId (not the data source as such) based on your own request parameters. This requires that you build your links yourself in your view/repeat controls

Comment: Per, I was thinking that you compute the data source on the xpage, and didn't get anywhere with that.  I understand building links myself, I currently have a view control but will likely change to a extjs grid at some point.  So you and Stephan are saying the link will overide the settings of 'Data source location', 'default action', and 'documentId' if I say ignoreRequestParams = true.  I will give it a shot.  Let me know if I got that wrong.  Thank you!

Comment: Didn't get a chance to try until today, wife just had baby #5. 
I got it to work!!!   I really like how it hides the fact that I separate my data from design.   Thank you both!

Comment: Congratulations to the new offspring. And glad it worked for you (both the offspring and the URLs)

Comment: In case anybody finding this post needs more info about how I implemented Stephan's answer, here is a blog post with more details: http://notesspeak.blogspot.com/2013/08/managing-unwieldy-urls-in-xpages.html